# Emit one observable after the other

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have 2 observables that are loading but they are not in the correct order when paged$ loads faster than firstLoad$. How can i correct this?

```
of(firstLoad$, paged$)
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((curr: Observable<ISubject[]>) => curr),
        scan((acc: ISubject[], curr: ISubject[]) => {
          if (acc.length > 0) {
            return [...curr];
          } else {
            return [...acc, ...curr];
          }
        }, [])
      )
      .subscribe((result) => {
        if (result.length === 0) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.loading = false;
          }, 300);
        } else {
          this.subjects = this.subjects.concat(result);
          this.errorStatus = Array(this.subjects.length);
          this.subjectsSubject$.next(this.subjects);
          this.loading = false;
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first: Do not use a subscription to set angular state. You will most likely run into ngExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError and for every emit the change detection will be triggered. Use the AyncPipe instead https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe.

But now to your question:

1. Why do you use of to pipe two observables together?

As I understood your question you want to have the result of paged$ in sequence to firstLoad$:

```
const firstLoad$ = [1, 2, 3];
const paged$ = [a, b, c];
firstLoad$.pipe(
    concatWith(paged$)
).subscribe((result) => console.log(result)); // console: [1, 2, 3], [a, b, c]
```

If paged$ is dependent on firstLoad$ use switchMap:

```
const firstLoad$ = [1, 2, 3];
const paged$ = [a, b, c];
firstLoad$.pipe(
    switchMap((fistLoad) => paged$.pipe(map((paged) => [...firstLoad, ...paged])
).subscribe((result) => console.log(result)); // console: [1, 2, 3, a, b, c]
```

Comment: I am wanting 2 service calls to be added together for a list

Comment: then it is approach two. You could also use switchMap if you like

Comment: removed the concatMap solution because it was wrong haha. Go with switchmap

Answer (score 0):

If the two observables are not dependent on each other, you can use [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) which will

> When all observables complete, emit the last emitted value from each.

```
forkJoin([firstLoad$, paged$])
      .pipe(
        map((values: Array<Array<ISubject>>) => {
          return [].concat.apply([], values);
        })
      )
      .subscribe((result) => {
        if (result.length === 0) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.loading = false;
          }, 300);
        } else {
          this.subjects = this.subjects.concat(result);
          this.errorStatus = Array(this.subjects.length);
          this.subjectsSubject$.next(this.subjects);
          this.loading = false;
        }
      });
```

Comment: forkJoin(firstLoad$, paged$) will trigger a deprecate warning. They recommend to put the orbservables in an array: forkJoin([firstLoad$, paged$]).

Comment: @DA updated thanks!

Comment: forkJoin([firstLoad$, paged$]) doesnt return [] is the problem it says

Comment: Type 'ISubject[]' is not assignable to type '[ISubject[], ISubject[]]'. @DA

Comment: @Joelad plz check now

Comment: ISubject[] cannot be used as an index type.

Comment: @Joelad sorry check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256258/discussion-between-joelad-and-naren-murali).